# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: A duplicate transaction has been submitted.'

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

Our Magento store is integrated with Authorize.net as a payment gateway. Our customers have been having issues checking out, and we have some weird issues going on.

We see payment notifications from authorize.net, but we don't see the customers order posted in magento. This is obviously a big issue, because our customers are getting charged, but we have no idea what they have ordered.

I have also noticed that these errors only happen when authorize.net is set to "authorize and capture" It seems to work when it is set to "authorize only".

I have pasted the error logs below:

```
2014-12-02T19:25:57+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: This transaction has been declined.' in /home/deccador/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(579): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(334): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 99.73, 'AUTH_ONLY')
#2 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(1086): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->authorize(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), 99.73)
#3 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(342): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_authorize(true, 99.73)
#4 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(886): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#5 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1104): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#6 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#7 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#8 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#9 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#10 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#11 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/Model/Type/Geo.php(684): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#12 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(508): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_Model_Type_Geo->saveOrder()
#13 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_IndexController->saveOrderAction()
#14 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#15 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/deccador/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/deccador/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
2014-12-02T22:31:26+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000003' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#7 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_invo...', Array)
#8 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#9 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#10 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2172): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#12 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#14 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#15 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#16 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#17 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/Model/Type/Geo.php(684): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#18 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(508): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_Model_Type_Geo->saveOrder()
#19 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_IndexController->saveOrderAction()
#20 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#21 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /home/deccador/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /home/deccador/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000003' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'' in /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#4 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#5 /home/deccador/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
#6 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('sales_flat_invo...', Array)
#7 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#8 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#9 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(2172): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#11 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#12 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#13 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#14 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#15 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#16 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/Model/Type/Geo.php(684): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#17 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(508): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_Model_Type_Geo->saveOrder()
#18 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_IndexController->saveOrderAction()
#19 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#20 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /home/deccador/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /home/deccador/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
2014-12-02T22:31:38+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Gateway error: A duplicate transaction has been submitted.' in /home/deccador/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(579): Mage::throwException('Gateway error: ...')
#1 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php(357): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->_place(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '354.11', 'AUTH_CAPTURE')
#2 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(443): Mage_Paygate_Model_Authorizenet->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment), '354.11')
#3 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(385): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice))
#4 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(608): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->capture()
#5 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(410): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->_invoice()
#6 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php(348): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->capture(NULL)
#7 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(886): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment->place()
#8 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1104): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_placePayment()
#9 [internal function]: Mage_Sales_Model_Order->place()
#10 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(105): call_user_func(Array)
#11 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Transaction.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->_runCallbacks()
#12 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(189): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Transaction->save()
#13 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(249): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitOrder()
#14 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/Model/Type/Geo.php(684): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll()
#15 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/local/Smartwave/OnepageCheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(508): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_Model_Type_Geo->saveOrder()
#16 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Smartwave_OnepageCheckout_IndexController->saveOrderAction()
#17 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#18 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/deccador/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/deccador/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/deccador/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Comment: Looks like you are reusing order IDS or something. Constraint error is telling you that. You need to either change your constraint criteria OR verify before attempting to complete the transaction.

Comment: Do you know why this would happen when we use authorize vs authorize and capture?

Comment: Could it be a problem with not clearing your cart session data and the same token is getting passed to the processor? In that case the processor could be noticing the same transation ID has already been used and rejecting the order.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am having the same issue. On top of it, some users are redirected to an empty cart upon clicking "place order." Did you ever get this fixed? If so would you mind sharing how? We're at wit's end!